# XCode Version 6.1 (6A1052d) update causes error: Overridden declaration here has type '(String?, AnyObject?) -> Bool'

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, swift, uistoryboardsegue

XCode automatically updated and after restarting I found that I have a number of errors.

Here is the line of code that is causing the error in question:

```
  override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
```

I'm not sure how to solve this one.

Can anybody give me some insight?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

`override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String?, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {`

I used autocomplete to redefine the method and it included a question mark after String.